# Migrating Grails 2.4 MultipleCompilationErrorsException

Tags: grails, intellij-idea, upgrade

I'm going to migrate an existing Grails 2.0 plugin to 2.4.
According to the [migration guide](http://grails.org/doc/2.4.3/guide/upgradingFrom23.html) the following steps were done:

- run set-grails-version 2.4.4
- update to latest plugin versions (hibernate4, tomcat, release and etc)

In in Intellij  I've changed plugin SDK version on 2.4.4. Now module->dependencies looks like

[image: this]

It looks good but when I do grails compile, I have MultipleCompilationErrorsException in SvnDeployer class of release:3.0.1 plugin with "unable to resolve" message: unable to resolve class **org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils**(it's strange, commons.io is included into grails library)

On SDK of 2.0 everything is fine, but when I change SDK version to 2.4, project can not be compiled.

Comment: Could you show the contents of your `plugins` section in BuildConfig.groovy? Something is leaking the svn plugin but that's easy enough to fix.

Comment: @BurtBeckwith, it's pretty standard:
`plugins { 
        build(":release:3.0.1",  
              ":rest-client-builder:1.0.3") {  
            export = false
        }
    }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience, Grails upgrades are not really smooth especially between feature releases.

I recommend starting with the usual
`grails clean`
`grails refresh-dependencies`
`grails compile`

After that check if you still get the same kind of errors, see whether or not excluding the svn plugin helps (if you're not using it).

Comment: thanks, I've discovered that Intellij command - change grails SDK is doing something wrong - so my receipt now is to create new project from existing sources using grails 2.4 as lib.